# Calculating the amount of "ink" of a specific pantone in an artboard in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, ink

Is there a way to calculate the amount of "ink" used on a specific artboard of a certain pantone ?

Let's say the percentage of space used by that pantone ?

I enclose an example...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's an Astute Graphics plugin called InkQuest. I haven't tried it so can't personally recommend it.

Comment: Its relative straightfoward to script too.

Comment: Unfortunately, @BillyKerr unless Astute has updated InkQuest, it [doesn't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l96kF.png) coverage percentages.

Comment: @Scott - Looks like they might have updated it. I was going by the graphic shown on their web site - the section titled "Ink Coverage" https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/inkquest - which shows coverage percentages, and area of ink coverage too.

Comment: Ahh.. It does look like they added coverage at some point.. or I just can't figure out where it is in my (older) version @BillyKerr `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If you can access Photoshop you can try the next idea; nothing must be installed nor purchased.

This 1200 px wide RGB image has 900 px wide black area and 300 px wide white area:

[image]

There's 25% of the area filled with white and the rest is black. As said the image is RGB.

After applying Filter > Blur > Average the result is this:

[image]

The color Picker shows that the brightness is 25% of full white, as expected.

Make a version of your image which has the shapes with the interesting color recolored to white and everything else is black. Copy and paste the image as pixels into a prepared empty RGB image which has the same height and width proportions.

Check that the colors are only full RGB black and full RGB white except the possible 1 px antialiased edges in Photoshop. Color space change, when the image is pasted, can cause a surprise; black isn't any more full RGB black and white is not full RGB white. But you can increase the contrast if needed in Photoshop. Find the percentage of white by applying Blur > Average.

The brightness resolution is only 1 percent, but that can be enough. You get more resolution by calculating for ex. from the red channel value. The wanted percentage is 100 x (R/255) percents.

Comment: Thank You so much for the explanation ! Not sure I got it though. I Will enclose an example.